# Remove everything from String which is not on a allowlist using regex

Tags: java, regex

Following regular expression removes each word from a string:

```
String regex = "\\b(operation|for the|am i|regex|mountain)\\b";
String sentence = "I am looking for the inverse operation by using regex";
String s = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(sentence.toLowerCase()).replaceAll("");
System.out.println(s); // output: "i am looking  inverse  by using "
```

I am looking for the inverse operation by using regex. So following example should work.
The words "am i" and "mountain" just indicate that there can be much more words in the list. And also words with spaces can occur in the list.

```
String regex = "<yet to find>"; // contains words operation,for the,am i,regex,mountain
String sentence = "I am looking for the inverse operation by using regex";
String s = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(sentence.toLowerCase()).replaceAll("");
System.out.println(s); // output: "  for the  operation  regex"
```

Regards, Harris

Comment: Thank you @GurmanjotSingh for your answer! It works like a charm except if I test string "hello". It returns "hello" instead of expected "".

Comment: I don't think a single regex replace can do it for you. IMHO the best way is to use a matcher for the positive regex and collect all the matches as the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the regex:

```
(?:(?!for the|operation|am i|mountain|regex).)*(for the|operation|am i|mountain|regex|$)
```

Replace the matches by contents of group 1 `\1` or `$1`

**[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/7oVCg7/1)**

**[Click for Code](https://regex101.com/r/7oVCg7/1/codegen?language=java)**

**Explanation:**

- `(?:(?!for the|operation|am i|mountain|regex).)*` - matches 0+ occurrences of any character that is NOT followed by either `for the` or `operation` or `am i` or `mountain` or `regex`
- `(for the|operation|am i|mountain|regex|$)` - matches either `for the` or `operation` or `am i` or `mountain` or `regex` or end of the string and captures it in group 1

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Singh's answer in the comments, I'd add that hard-coding the regex for a set of words is not very portable. What if the words change? Are they just words or are they patterns? Can you isolate the part of code that will do this work and test it?

Assuming they're just words:

1. Define a whitelist

   ```
   String[] whitelist = {
      "operation",
      "for",
      "the",
      "am i",
      "regex",
      "mountain"
   };
   ```
2. Write a method for filtering the words so that only the whitelisted ones are allowed.

   ```
    String sanitized(String raw, String[] whitelist) {
        StringBuilder termsInOr = new StringBuilder();
        termsInOr.append("|");
        for (String word : whitelist) {
            termsInOr.append(word);
        }
        String regex = ".*?\\b(" + termsInOr.substring(1) + ")\\b";
        return Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE)
            .matcher(raw)
            .replaceAll(subst);
    }
   ```

This way the logic is isolated, you have two inputs - a whitelist and the raw string - and the sanitized output. It can be tested with assertions based on your expected output (test cases) if you have a different whitelist or raw string somewhere else in the code you can call the method with that whitelist / raw string to sanitize.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This regex is working great for strings which contain at least one allow list item. But if I test "hello" against this regex, it returns "hello" instead of "".